# How to control Focus mode across devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, notifications, focus

I've recently made the jump to go all-in on Apple, so I have 2 iPads (one for my daughter), a watch, and an iPhone. I have my iCloud+ account connected to each. I want to be able to control notifications and potentially sync for each of the devices with specialized settings for each; for example:

- I want to disable notifications and disconnect messages from my daughter's iPad
- I want to silence notifications on my iPad while I'm at my desk so the screen isn't turning on every time I get a notification

It seems like the Focus mode is the right way to control notifications, but I want to be able to configure it independently for each device, and it seems like it syncs across them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this buy going to *System Settings → Focus* and toggling the setting “Share across devices.”  It’s enabled by default.

For full details, see Apple’s Support Document [Set up a Focus on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchl613dc43f/13.0/mac/13.0) and [Use Focus on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608)

[image: Share Focus iOS Screen]

Comment: Do you need to have the same Apple ID on all devices? I would think they don't have the same Apple ID.

Comment: @Thinkr I do have the same Apple ID on each. I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you!